# Initialize a Dictionary with values in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, dictionary, c#-2.0

In C# 2.0 we can initialize arrays and lists with values like this:

```
int[] a = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
int[,] b = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 } };
List<int> c = new List<int>(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 });
```

I would like to do the same with Dictionary. I know you can do it easily in C# 3.0 onwards like this:

```
Dictionary<int, int> d = new Dictionary<int, int> { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 } };
```

But it doesn't work in C# 2.0. Is there any workaround for this without using `Add` or basing on an already existing collection?

Comment: What's constraining you to still use C# 2? Life is so much better from C# 3 onwards, even if you're targeting .NET 2, that it's worth trying to muse a more recent compiler...

Comment: Ha ha, I was wondering if I should ask for not answering the way you did. Working with C# 2 is a requirement which I can't do much about. I know newer C# versions make things easier, but since I already ran into this problem, I figured I would ask out of curiosity.

Comment: I'm intrigued as to *why* there's this requirement though. Being limited to .NET 2.0 I can understand, but C# 2 seems an odder requirement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But it doesn't work in C# 2.0. Is there any workaround for this without using Add or basing on an already existing collection?

No. The closest I can think of would be to write your own `DictionaryBuilder` type to make it simpler:

```
public class DictionaryBuilder<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary
        = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary();

    public DictionaryBuilder<TKey, TValue> Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't add after building");
        }
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    public Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Build()
    {
        Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ret = dictionary;
        dictionary = null;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
Dictionary<string, int> x = new DictionaryBuilder<string, int>()
    .Add("Foo", 10)
    .Add("Bar", 20)
    .Build();
```

This is at least a *single expression* still, which is useful for fields where you want to initialize at the point of declaration.

Comment: Skeet, your fluent syntax wouldn't work because `Add` doesn't `return this;`.

Comment: @Mechanical Object: Thanks for fixing the quote, but please don't change the *semantics* of code in other people's answers without checking first. I very deliberately have the code the way it is: I would consider it an *error* to add the same key multiple times; I don't want to silently ignore it. (An alternative would be to use the indexer, which would just overwrite the old entry instead - again, that would be silently hiding a problem though.)

Comment: You forgot to add return this again, fixed that :)